# Can I get notifications from Stack Overflow on my Android phone?

Tags: support, notifications

How can I get notifications from the Stack Overflow account on my Android mobile phone?

Comment: Probably not. Maybe if the app was still supported

Comment: Yes. Enable email notifications and install an email app that sends you push notifications.

Comment: There was the official Stack Exchange Android app, but [it was suddenly delisted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353133). Note that the app is already abandoned, but it is still possible to download and install the APK from alternative sites (such as [APK Mirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-stack-exchange/stack-exchange-stack-exchange-1-0-95-release/stack-exchange-1-0-95-android-apk-download/)). From personal experience, the notification is still working on my device, but some users had issues with it. YMMV.